# How to rank bucket sort results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a leaderboard query in elastic search, I have documents with parent-child relationship,
Parent Doc: Player
Child Doc: Team
A player can be in multiple teams.

I am calculating total score for each team and sorting the results using bucket sort, and I am getting correct sorted results.

i want to get a rank of each team in sorted results, for example in a 1000 teams totals results in each bucket value i should get a key something like Rank: 1 which is a index of that value in 1000 sorted results;

Here is my current attempt:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "contest_teams"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "challenge_id": 212
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "team": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "team_score": {
          "parent": {
            "type": "team_player"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_points": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "points"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "team_points_bucket_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "team_score.total_points": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 2,
            "from": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could yo please share your mapping? Alternatively when you mean parent-child do you mean its as mentioned in this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: Yes I used join type where Player is parent and Team is child, and having one-to-many relationship.